# Find who edited google calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api

We have a shared calender and we want to find out who edited or deleted the event using google calender api. Is there anyway we can find out this?

Answer (score 1):

You need [Calendar audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6110475?hl=en).

> Track calendar notifications and view changes to your users’
>   calendars, events, and subscriptions

You can follow the steps provided to find out who have made changes in you public calendar.

Using the API, you can visit [Calendar Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar).